# Creating a mesh from a point cloud?

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh

*I'd like to create a mesh from a point cloud generated by video tracking, ideally using python for some kind of prototype at least.*

Initially I thought this is a fairly easy task, connecting the vertices, creating the faces, done ;) Then I've read that [Screened Poisson Surface Reconstruction](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Code/PoissonRecon/Version9.01/) is currently the best approach. Although there is a nice [github repository](https://github.com/mkazhdan/PoissonRecon) and code to play with, it's hard to understand the papers.

**Q:** Is there another clever implementation/approach you would recommend or is *Screened Poisson Surface Reconstruction* the way to go? Any suggestion how to implement that as simple as possible will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you mention any other requirements? Do you need the fastest / most memory efficient approach, or the simplest one to implement to get on with prototyping?

Comment: Maybe this question on stackoverflow helps: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838761/robust-algorithm-for-surface-reconstruction-from-3d-point-cloud)

Comment: Have you tried using [MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/)? It's one of its use cases by design.

Comment: Performance doesn't matter. I think understanding the concepts and accuracy is more important. Sorry if the question is too broad, but I thought that any experiences from experts, how to dive in and which concept is worth it, would be helpful for me and potential future visitors @trichoplax

Answer (score 2):

There is algorithm called as delaunay triangulation which does triangulation or points it's comparably simple to understand . But it is very slow. If you don't want to implement your own algorithm from scratch please have look at pcl 
http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/greedy_projection.php
Also have look at CGAL
http://www.cgal.org.

Comment: As a hint for the people wanting to learn this, the delaunay triangulation can be build with voronoi diagrams. A vornoi diagram takes an unordered set of points and calculates vornoi regions such that each region contains exactly one point and the border of a region is set such that the two points of the bordering fields have exactly the same distance to the border.

Once the voronoi diagram is build, the delaunay triangulation is a simple matter of connecting each point with the points of the neighbouring voronoi regions.